# Option with optional argument

Tags: python, docopt

Suppose that I have

```
My program

Usage:
  myprog [options]

Options:
  -h, --help        Show this screen.
      --version     Show version.
      --files=<arg> Files. [default: foo.txt]
```

I would like to distinguish in my code:

- `--files` not specified.
- `--files` specified, but with no argument to accept the default.
- `--files myfile`, i.e. `--files` specified with custom argument.

With the current docstring I can either

- Not specify `--files`.
- Specify `--files` with an argument.

So I'm missing:

- The option to specify `--files` without an argument.
- Distinguish if `--files` was specified, or if the user specified `--files foo.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to specify the `--files` argument in the main usage string. For example:

```
# dopt.py
from docopt import docopt

dstr = """My program

Usage:
  myprog [--files [FNAME]] [options]

Options:
  -h, --help        Show this screen.
      --version     Show version.
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arguments = docopt(dstr)
    print(arguments)
```

This essentially makes `--files` a true/false argument and adds another argument `FNAME` to hold the file name.
Usage:

```
$ python dopt.py
{'--files': False,
 '--help': False,
 '--version': False,
 'FNAME': None}

$ python dopt.py --files
{'--files': True,
 '--help': False,
 '--version': False,
 'FNAME': None}

$ python dopt.py --files abc.txt
{'--files': True,
 '--help': False,
 '--version': False,
 'FNAME': 'abc.txt'}
```

Then, you can use the value of `--files` and `FNAME` from the returned `dict` to infer what to do:

```py
if not arguments['--files']:
    print("Not using files")
elif not arguments['FNAME']:
    print("Using default file foo.txt")
else:
    print(f"Using file {arguments['FNAME']}")
```

A pitfall to remember: you can also specify `FNAME` independently of `--files`. So this also works, and it might interfere with other arguments, so be sure to test all combinations thoroughly:

```
$ python dopt.py abc.txt
{'--files': False,
 '--help': False,
 '--version': False,
 'FNAME': 'abc.txt'}
Not using files
```

---

Personally, I prefer using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) because it's less ambiguous. It builds the doc string from the prescribed arguments, not the other way round.

In `argparse`, an argument can have a default value and you can specify that it can take zero or one argument using `nargs="?"`. Then, you can specify a `const="foo.txt"` value which the argument will take if no values are given. For example:

```
# dopt.py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--files", required=False, default=None, nargs="?", const="foo.txt")
p = parser.parse_args()
print(p)
```

And running this:

```
$ python dopt.py
Namespace(files=None)

$ python dopt.py --files
Namespace(files='foo.txt')

$ python dopt.py --files abc.txt
Namespace(files='abc.txt')
```

And it even handles the "no `--files`" case correctly:

```
$ python dopt.py abc.txt
usage: dopt.py [-h] [--files [FILES]]
dopt.py: error: unrecognized arguments: abc.txt
```

Comment: If I understand correctly in docopt I couldn’t have two such options, because of the use as argument? (But I could in argparse)

Comment: I didn't know docopt could even do this until I tried a bunch of things, so this is by no means a definitive answer, but from a quick try with `myprog [--files [FNAME]] [--speed [SPD]] [options]` as the usage string, it seems to work fine. Same pitfalls apply though - you can specify `FNAME` and `SPD` even without `--files` and `--speed`. The first argument goes to `FNAME`, the second to `SPD`. @TomdeGeus

Comment: `python dopt.py --files abc.txt --speed 20` gives 
`{'--files': True,
 '--help': False,
 '--speed': True,
 '--version': False,
 'FNAME': 'abc.txt',
 'SPD': '20'}`