# Overwrite help string

Tags: python, argparse

Inside my project I'm mostly using docopt, but [to overcome a limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64864201/2646505) I'm switching to argparse for one function. However, for consistency I want to still print my own doc-string when I type `-h` or `--help`. Surprisingly I cannot find how to do that.

This doesn't work:

```py
parser.add_argument('-h', '--help', action='help', default=argparse.SUPPRESS, help=__doc__)
```

as it gives

```
argparse.ArgumentError: argument -h/--help: conflicting option strings: -h, --help
```

But what *do* I have to put?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using the same option multiple times in Python's argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36166225/using-the-same-option-multiple-times-in-pythons-argparse)

Comment: @SerialLazer Thanks. I'm not sure... Or rather I don't think so. What I want to do it simply to pring something else when `argparse` would print the docstring, I don't want to add an option on top of it. But maybe I'm overlooking something?

Comment: `--help` is included by default; so that's why adding your own produces a conflict.  There is a `ArgumentParser` parameter to turns off the automatic help argument.  Specifying the `help=__doc__` doesn't help since the just changes the help line in the conventional help display.  It doesn't change the whole display.

Answer (score 1):

I found that one solution is to overwrite the default `print_help` function, as follows:

```py
import argparse

class Parser(argparse.ArgumentParser):

    def print_help(self):
        print(__doc__)

parser = Parser()
parser.add_argument('-f', '--foo', required=False)
```

Comment: I think this the best.  `ipython` accomplishes something similar by looking at `sys.argv` before using the `argparse` parser.  In other words, it captures the `help` command first.